# Group Theory for Beginners

Tags: group-theory

I have studied maths at A-Level and have part of an Open University maths degree. I will be studying Group Theory next but I missed the registration deadline and now have to wait until October to start my course. I am therefore keen to get ahead and do some preparatory work. I tried to find the actual course materials but have had no luck.

I am therefore looking for suggested reading materials to give me a good start in Group Theory to prepare me for my course later in the year.

Any ideas?